# Difference between apache spark 2 and cloudera spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

i searched but couldn't get a concrete difference between the Apache distribution of spark 2 and the Cloudera distribution of spark 2. Can anybody help me on this in understanding the differences they have in spark core, spark sql and spark streaming.

Answer (score 2):

They are referring to the same thing.  Cloudera distributes a packaged version of Hadoop including Apache Spark 2.  There are slight differences in this Apache Spark 2 and the latest upstream version of Spark 2 from https://spark.apache.org/.  These are usually spelled out in the [Release Notes for CDH Spark 2](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_release_notes.html).

For example, the release notes have a section called: [Spark 2 Known Issues](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_known_issues.html#known_issues) which describe some missing features.

[image]

In general, incompatibilities arise because there is a lag between upstream releases and CDH releases and CDH has to maintain major version compatibility between minor releases.